# Подскажите пожалуйста как сложить числовые значения смешанного списка используя сравнение вида type(5)==int. в pyton

Tags: python, list

Подскажите пожалуйста как сложить числовые значения смешанного списка используя сравнение вида `type(5)==int`.
Пример списка:

```
L=[-2, 5, 9.0, 'строка', -7.8]
```

Comment: `for x in lst: if isinstance(x, (int, float)):`

Comment: Спасибо. Но надо использовать сравнение вида type(5)==int и метод isinstance я еще не проходил.

Comment: ну и подставьте в if то, что нужно сиспользовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
L=[-2, 5, 9.0, 'строка', -7.8]
print(sum(x for x in L if type(x) == int))
```

Хотя вы наверняка ещё списковых и генераторных сокращений не проходили, но вы же можете написать обычный цикл.

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось!!! Только для таких же чайников как я поясню, что еще в код надо добавить  or type(x) == float, так как надо сложить все числовые значения списка.